# How do I make changes in base.css for WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

I need to change an image background for some blog posts on a website using WordPress. I've tracked the element source to be located in the base.css. As far as I can tell I don't have direct access to edit the file, but I'm assuming that there is somewhere that I can modify it. I want to change the background style of the Testimonial posts on the Testimonials page. The element that I need to modify is testi-container's url image. Here is the website address. [www.avantirecruiters.com](http://avantirecruiters.com)

How can I change the style using CSS?

Comment: Target the bg-img with body class as every wordpress page have an idvdual class allocated to the body tag.

Comment: You can override this style in custom.css
Appearance->edit->custom.css

Comment: The element is .testi-container and it's located in base.css. When I try to edit the style.css it doesn't work. Here is the code I implemented. `.testi-container {
background-image: none;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have class called body class called 'category-testimonials'
.category-testimonials .testi-container 
for image you  can always use 
.category-testimonials .testi-container{background:url('');}

Comment: I tried adding your suggestion to the bottom of style.css. The main style sheet I have access to and your solution doesn't work

Comment: Nevermind. I figured out how to implement your solution. I have to add it to the Additional CSS in the Appearance -> Customize section of WordPress. Thank you!